# npgsql connection pool repeated authentication

Tags: c#, npgsql, ef-core-2.2

I'm using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.1.2, EfCore 2.2, asp.net 3.1.

Connection pooling is enabled (not passing it in the connection string).
After enabling logging I'm getting logs like this:

```
2021-05-19 10:23:21.542 +02:00 Opening connection...
2021-05-19 10:23:21.545 +02:00 Attempting to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432
2021-05-19 10:23:21.595 +02:00 Socket connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432
2021-05-19 10:23:21.597 +02:00 Authenticating...
2021-05-19 10:23:21.914 +02:00 A PostgreSQL type with the name hstore was not found in the database
2021-05-19 10:23:21.916 +02:00 A PostgreSQL type with the name citext was not found in the database
2021-05-19 10:23:21.918 +02:00 A PostgreSQL type with the name unknown was not found in the database
2021-05-19 10:23:21.921 +02:00 Opened connection to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432
```

This behavior is repeated for each query that's performed. As you can see, it seems that each time it performs a new authentication (it takes 300ms).
Seen like this is seems that connection pooling is not working since I expect the connection to be reused each time. I also tryed to add dbcontextpooling, the result stays the same.
Any hint?

Comment: You're going to have to submit a minimal code sample, so that we can see what you're doing. DbContext pooling isn't related to database connection pooling in any way - it's purely about pooling DbContext instances in memory. Note also that EF Core 2.2 is out of support and quite old by now, consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, I found out that each time a connection was closed we were emptying the pool explicitly :(